# Regular expression: zero or more occurrences of optional character /

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression pattern to say:

> zero or more occurrences of the character `/`

?

Comment: You should also state which regex flavor/implementation you're using.

Comment: Yep could not remember difference between +/* was having mental block!..https://regex101.com/ is good for this too. Just hover over symbol in their website where you've put your regex.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
/*
```

If your delimiters are slash-based, escape it:

```
\/*
```

`*` means "0 or more of the previous repeatable pattern", which can be a single character, a character class or a group.

Comment: I was always wondered: why in the command line the `*` character means "Any count of any characters"? So we can seek i.e. for all the files that begins with *foo* by `ls foo*`. It is very confusing.

Comment: That's because in the shell globbing is used which is not a regular expression. They both allow matching of patterns but are completely different.