# javascript regex difference between two regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split

what is the difference between these 2 regexes?  This is the split function in javascript, and str is just a string var.

```
str.split(/; */)
str.split(/;/)
```

Thanks

Comment: The former would split by `;` followed by any number of spaces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression: zero or more occurrences of optional character /](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304360/regular-expression-zero-or-more-occurrences-of-optional-character)

Answer (score 2):

The first example will split on `;` followed by the space character (`0` or more times)

```
"aaa;bbb;    ccc;  ddd".split(/; */)
// => [ 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd' ]
```

Where the second example will simply split on the `;` character itself.

```
"aaa;bbb;    ccc;  ddd".split(/;/)
// => [ 'aaa', 'bbb', '    ccc', '  ddd' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one will split "a;  b" to ["a","b"], and the second one will split to ["a","  b"].