# Regex: ignoring whitespace and matches the next digits

Tags: python, regex

My regex expression take the `Jan 26 00:00:15` through this code:

```
re.search(r'^(\w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', line).group(0)
```

String:

```
Jan 26 00:00:15 111.111.11.12 pppoe,ppp,info
```

but erasing the digit "2" I have two whitespace and this return an error, using pythex, analyzing this string:

```
Jan  6 00:00:15 111.111.11.12 pppoe,ppp,info
Jan 26 00:00:15 111.111.11.12 pppoe,ppp,info
```

I got it to ignore these whitespace: `^\w{3}[^"]`, sometimes my day has 1 digit or 2 digits. How can I take them?

Comment: `\w{3}\s+\d{1,2}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression: zero or more occurrences of optional character /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304360/regular-expression-zero-or-more-occurrences-of-optional-character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Regex range specifier `{1,2}` to strictly match 1 to 2 occurrence(s) of the preceding token.

Do:

```
^\w{3}\s{1,2}\d{1,2}\s(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}
```

Additionally, i have used `(?:\d{2}:){2}`: here, the non-capturing group `(?:\d{2}:)` matches two digits, followed by a `:`, and `{2}` after that matches the token two times -- this is to match `HH:MM` so that wo don't have to repeat ourselves. `\d{2}` after that matches `SS`.

Example:

```
In [40]: [re.search(r'^\w{3}\s{1,2}\d{1,2}\s(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}', s).group() for s in l]
Out[40]: ['Jan 26 00:00:15', 'Jan  6 00:00:15']
```

Answer (score 3):

I will add a space to the character class for the first digit.

```
re.search(r'^(\w{3} [ \d]\d \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', line).group(0)
```

This way it is strictly conform to the format and can't match something like:
`Jan                          2 18:54:02` or 
`Jan  12 18:54:02`

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
re.search(r'^(\w{3} +\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', line).group(0)
```

Tip: http://regex101.com I use this all the time when I am in need for a regex.